# I am having Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider when I call modal on click div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

```
<div ng-click="openReviewUploadedVideoPopup()"></div>
```

in html I am having this div on click I want to open a modal

```
        $scope.openReviewUploadedVideoPopup = function(){
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl:'app/appModules/homeModule/popup/_reviewUploadedVideo.html',
        controller: 'PostAttachmentCtrl',
        backdrop: 'static',
        size: 'lg'
    });
};
```

Above code is written in controller, but I am getting error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: attachmentProvider <- attachment <- PostAttachmentCtrl
```

Comment: post your controller code

Comment: homeModule.controller('NewsFeedCtrl', function($scope, $modal) {    $scope.openReviewUploadedVideoPopup = function(){
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl:'app/appModules/homeModule/popup/_reviewUploadedVideo.html',
        controller: 'PostAttachmentCtrl',
        backdrop: 'static',
        size: 'lg'
    });
};  }

Comment: add it to the question, i think still you are missing something in controller code

Comment: post the `PostAttachmentCtrl` controller also

Comment: what is attachment ?? is it service ??

Comment: Please share the PostAttachmentCtrl code also